# Can a PTFE coated wire heat up enough to be used as a heating element

Tags: resistance, heat, wire

I saw a comment on [another post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/427461/12v-nichrome-wire-water-heater-is-it-safe) about using PTFE coated copper wire as a heating element for a thermos. Would this setup really work under low power(the comment said the source was a usb port) as I assume the PTFE will insulate some of the heat.

Will this be a suitable material for my project. I am trying to keep a mug warm using a wireless charging pad (~7.5W).

Comment: Somewhere around 400C, PTFE decomposes to release HF. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrofluoric_acid Not something I want anywhere near MY thermos. (Not that 7.5W will get it close to that temperature).

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you dissipate 7.5W in a resistive load you get 7.5W of heat, regardless of what kind of wire you use. What do you mean by "heat up that much"? What do you mean by "low power"? What is the gauge of the wire?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have edited the post to try and clarify. My main goal is to design a small heating element that can sit inside the mug and heat up the contents, and I didnt want to have exposed metal inside as that could react with the liquid, both chemically and electrically.  Is there a better material?

Comment: @Brian Drummond -- they put it on cookware, do they not? It is arguably the most inert of all plastic materials at ordinary temperatures.

Comment: @Shimon Jacobs -- if you can buy it in the form you want, it would in principle be hard to beat for contamination, IMO (although preparations of a polymer vary quite a bit and you may have small amounts of unreacted process chemicals in there, especially if it is not food grade.). Where PTFE falls down is mechanical properties.

Comment: If you're thinking of making something like a puck to drop in a ceramic mug and then place on a heating pad, you'll have a challenge coupling the field at that distance.  If you're thinking of building the heater right into the mug's bottom you'd have an easier time.

Comment: It might work but the best way to do this is with a flexible circuit heater. They use these for rearview mirrors and similar. It is nichrome foil on polyimide substrate (typical flex circuit substrate). You can also use copper on polyimide substrate. This is just a generic flex circuit with a serpentine copper trace engineered to give you the desired resistance.

Comment: 7.5 W is liable to be VERY inadequate. Water heats at 850 litre.degrees per kWh. With say 100 ml of water and 7.5W you will need about 1000 x 3600 / 850 / 0.1 = 424 seconds to heat 1 degree C with perfect insulation. 10 ml requires 42 s/degree C. || The fact that for water: 850 litre.degrees-C = 1 kWh is an immensely useful fact.

Comment: Using a resistor that suits your needs is liable to be a superior solution. Seal the wires (and the resistor if needed) in an inert coating. PTFE and copper will require a far larger amount of wire than is convenient.

Comment: @K H-- yes the plan is to mount the electronics on the underside of the mug, and drill holes in the bottom of the mug so the heating element can be inside the mug.

Comment: @mkeith-- flexible circuit heaters sound like exactly what i need. ill look into them.

Comment: @Russell McMahon-- thanks for those figures, ill crunch the numbers and see if it will work for me, I only want to delay the cooling, so it might still work

Comment: Measure rate of temperature decline. Then calculate litre degrees per time of cooling. That allows you to calculate Wh of energy being lost and thus watts over that time period. Eg to make sums easy assume 0.1 litre drops 8.5 degrees C in 6 minutes. So 0.85 litre degrees drop in 6 mins so 8.5 l.degrees in 1 hour = 8.5/850 = 0.01 kWh per hour = 10 watt.. adjust data to suit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Water has good thermal conductivity, so the PTFE won't 'insulate the heat' to any noticeable extent provided the the wire is long enough to spread it out. The wire inside might get a bit hotter, but PTFE can withstand up to 260 °C. With the outside being kept cool by the water the inside should not get anywhere near that temperature.

Vacuum flasks are designed to minimize heat loss, so a small heater can work. In [one test](https://outdoorsmagic.com/article/best-thermos-flasks-reviewed/) a 500 ml Thermos dropped from 90 °C to 75 °C in 8 hours. Water has a specific heat capacity of 4182 J/kg.°C, so 500 ml dropping 15 °C in 8 hours corresponds to an average power loss of ~1.1W. That means anything over 1.1W would be enough to (eventually) heat that Thermos flask to 75-90 °C and keep it there.

A typical mug only holds ~250 ml, but the heat loss is far greater. In [this test](https://protonsforbreakfast.wordpress.com/2018/11/07/mug-cooling-initial-results/) a vacuum insulated mug took ~65 minutes to drop from 90 °C to 75 °C, but a basic ceramic mug lost the same amount in less than 15 minutes. However as temperature gets closer to ambient the heat loss slows down. At 50 °C the ceramic mug lost ~9 °C in 15 minutes, which corresponds to ~10W in 250 ml.

[image]

So your 7.5 W should be enough to keep a vacuum insulated mug with lid warm, but may not be sufficient for a standard mug.

Comment: Just as a point of reference, a good temperature for consuming hot liquids is in the 50C to 60C range.  Anything beyond that will likely be uncomfortable to the consumer.

Comment: @Brucce Abbott-- thanks for the informative reply. i suppose if i am putting 7.5w in while 10w is leaving, it will still cool down but at a slow enough rate for me to finish my coffee.

Answer (score -1):

Copper has a very low resistance, so it will require a lot of current to dissipate any appreciable power (even 7.5W would need many amps).

PTFE covered resistance wire is available, if you are prepared to buy enough of it. For an example, refer to [this link](http://hightechflon.com/NiCr-PTFE-resistance-heating-cutting-wire-0,90-mm/Page-16-2-120-223.aspx)

Comment: No, you have completely ignored the **gauge** of the wire. A very thin copper wire can consume several watts at low current (if the voltage is high enough, of course).

Comment: For 10 feet of 28 gauge wire wrap wire (quite a lot to heat a cup) you'd need about 3.4A at 2.2V to dissipate 7.5W. If you use a properly selected nichrome wire you can use much less wire and be able to more easily choose your voltages and currents to suit a USB supply.

Comment: So if I use a long enough wire, maybe even smaller than 28 gauge, I can get 7.5W with less than an ampere? The OP didn't say anything about the maximum length of the wire or how it would be physically configured in the original question. So, taken exactly as you wrote it, the phrase "would need many amps" is incorrect. You **can** dissipate 7.5W in copper wire without "many amps".